# php mysqli event get by date

Tags: php, mysqli

I have made a code where I get all nubers in the month then I am adding on events from my database. I need the numbers to come from the database in $sqldates I am now only getting array as when I echo the $sqldates. I have 4, 10, 22 and 26 in my database now.

This is what I am getting now look at the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7qxT.jpg)

This is the result I want look at this picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWy19.jpg)

How do I get the results from my database as picture 2 shows? Pleas help how to get the numbers from array.

```
    <table>
    <?php
     //database connent
        include 'con.php'; 
      //get day from event
   $sql = "SELECT day, color FROM events";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);



$sqldates = array(array('day', 'color_value'), array('date_value', 'color_value'), array('date_value', color_value));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
array_push($sqldates, $row['day'], $row['color'] );
echo $row['day'];

} 
$counter = 0;
//first day
  $firstday = '1';

  $two = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2018); // 31
//for loop get all day in month  
  for ($number = $firstday; $number <= $two; $number++)


    if (in_array($number , $sqldates)) {
        echo "<td width=50 bgcolor='#{$sqldates[$counter][1]}'>$sqldates[$counter][0]</td>";
        $counter++;
      } else {
        echo"<td width=50 bgcolor='#1e8e8e'>$number</td>";
      }        
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Just echo `$number` instead of `$sqldates`...?

Comment: No the $number gives me the result from php. I need to get the numbers from the database. 
The $sqldates var.

Comment: Right, but `$sqldates` is the array of numbers you want in red, `$number` is the number itself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your updated question this should be good guide:

```
<table>
        <?php
         //database connect
            include 'con.php'; 
          //get day from event
          $sql = "SELECT day, color FROM events";
          $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

          $sqldates = array();
          $colors = array();
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
              array_push($sqldates, $row['day']);
              array_push($colors, $row['color']);
          }

          //first day
           $firstday = '1';

          $two = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2018); // 31
          //for loop get all day in month  
           $counter = 0;
          for ($number = $firstday; $number <= $two; $number++)

          if (in_array($number , $sqldates)) {
              echo "<td width=50 bgcolor='$colors[$counter]'>$sqldates[$counter]</td>";
              $counter++;
            } else {
              echo"<td width=50 bgcolor='#1e8e8e'>$number</td>";
          }
      ?>
    </table>
```

Note that you need to have defined color for each day, otherwise you will get "Undefined offset" notice.

Comment: In this solution you actually store value in one, and color in another array (arrays need to be the same size). Using this you can have different color for each day stored in your db.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to echo an array. Instead you should echo a value from that array with specified index. If I am not wrong, this should work:

```
//first day
  $firstday = '1';

  $two = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2018); // 31
  //for loop get all day in month  
  $counter = 0;
  for ($number = $firstday; $number <= $two; $number++)

    if (in_array($number , $sqldates)) {
        echo"<td width=50 bgcolor='#f44242'>$sqldates[$counter]</td>";
        $counter++;
      } else {
        echo"<td width=50 bgcolor='#1e8e8e'>$number</td>";
      }
```

Comment: It is inside a for loop when I add your code I only get one green cell with 32 in it. Think the loop affect your answer. It almost works when I do echo"<td width=50 bgcolor='#f44242'>$sqldates[0]</td>"; but still wrong then I am getting 4 in each red cell.

Comment: Just put $counter = 0; before for loop and it will work :)

Comment: Ok that worked. If i want to add a second row in my array to get the color from my database is that a big change? Add the row $row['color'])

Comment: That depends on your approach... You could go with a multidimensional array.  So you would get something like this:
$sqldates = array(array('date_value', 'color_value'), array('date_value', 'color_value'), array('date_value', color_value)); etc.
And when you read from this array:

echo "<td width=50 bgcolor='{$sqldates[$counter][1]}'>$sqldates[$counter][0]</td>";
But first version is much cleaner and easier to understand. 
I hope this was helpful :)

Comment: I updated my code did not get where do I put the row $row['color'] ?